# Peer to peer navigation in WinUI3

Tags: c#, winui-3

I am trying to do a peer-to-peer navigation - navigate from `MainWindow` (extends `Window` class) to `HomePage` (extends `Page` class). I am not using MVVM architecture (it's an overkill for what I am doing).

Here is my `MainWindow` code:

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private readonly Frame _frame;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
        this.Content = _frame = new Frame();
    }

    private void userButtonDynamic_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        _ = _frame. Navigate(typeof(HomePage), null, new SlideNavigationTransitionInfo()
                { Effect = SlideNavigationTransitionEffect.FromBottom });
    }
}
```

This is working, but the page transition is snappy, and no effects are working, in this case, a smoother slide navigation from bottom to the next page.

Is there a way to make the transition smoother or do I have to leave the `MainWindow` empty and on startup add the `HomePage` to it and take it from there?

Comment: I can't reproduce you issue. Though I did a few changes to your code, like adding a `Button` in `MainWindow.xaml` and place the `_frame` there. Navigation and transition effect worked as expected. Can you be more specific about your issue and post a minimal reproducible code?

Comment: [reproduced](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cOgDv.gif) with my project and [WindowsAppSDK-Samples/Input](https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK-Samples/blob/640e103afd33cea7984eeb1f62aa05c29064c52b/Samples/Input/cs-winui/MainPage.xaml.cs#L75). Other animations all don't work. I have checked if there is something I missed compared to [Implement navigation between two pages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/apps/design/basics/navigate-between-two-pages?tabs=wasdk). You can submit an issue at https://github.com/microsoft/WindowsAppSDK/issues.